# GeoServer REST API: How to get list of workspaces by username

Tags: geoserver, rest, workspace

Is it possible to get list of available workspaces and list of data stores in some workspace for some specific user with GeoServer REST API by sending request with admin user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such functionality is not available.

Could be implemented I believe, not entirely trivial though, the security system is transparent to the service and configuration code, believe one would have to switch the current login by code, pretending to be the other user.